# Scrollview is not scrolled in Linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview, android-layout-weight

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/img1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/abc" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/iv4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ ooo eeee oo oof nn aaaaa tt pppppp yyyy sssssss eeeeeeee iiiiiiiiiii. oo ggggg, eeeeee ttttt ttt yyyyy oo oooo eeeeeeee aag" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/opz" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Scrollbar is not viewing inside the layout.
I tried visibility and isScrollContainer but Scrollbar is not working so can anybody help me out to make this Layout Scrollable.

The Text mentioned in tv3 whole text is not visible so I wanted to make it scrollable so every text can be visible.

Comment: you haven't closed the </ScrollView> tag ... close it and try again

Comment: I closed the tag at the end of the layout Darkie

Comment: I think the items inside your ScrollView are not large enough to fill it, so there is no need to scroll anything. Do you want to show the scrollbar even when the ScrollView cannot scroll?

Comment: @moictab text : You eeee oo oof nn aaaaa tt pppppp yyyy sssssss eeeeeeee iiiiiiiiiii. oo ggggg, eeeeee ttttt ttt yyyyy oo oooo eeeeeeee aag in tv3 
it cuts down the text...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal" >
```

close `</ScrollView>` tag at the end of the xml and then try again ... you are not closing the scrollview tag...

Comment: @Chaow can you provide the screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

In LinearLayout, you have given weight 1 that's why it's taking space as much as available. So no scrolling is needed.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

better use wrap_content for layout height and remove weight. And it should be something like..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I put this Layout because two layouts ll2 and ll1 both looks in similar size in two parts..

Comment: Monsur Hossain Toni :  You eeee oo oof nn aaaaa tt pppppp yyyy sssssss eeeeeeee iiiiiiiiiii. oo ggggg, eeeeee ttttt ttt yyyyy oo oooo eeeeeeee aag in tv3 is not visible so wanted to make it scrollable I put the weight because two ll1 and ll2 are two similar weight parts of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested Linear layouts have layout_weigh="1". This has the same effect as setting your layout height to fill_parent, filing the entire scrollview with one layout.

Try removing the layout_weight attributes and set your linearlayout heights to wrap_content.

Comment: I put this Layout because two layouts ll2 and ll1 both looks in similar size in two parts..

Comment: You eeee oo oof nn aaaaa tt pppppp yyyy sssssss eeeeeeee iiiiiiiiiii. oo ggggg, eeeeee ttttt ttt yyyyy oo oooo eeeeeeee aag in tv3 is not visible so wanted to make it scrollable I put the weight because two ll1 and ll2 are two similar weight parts of the layout.

Comment: Do you want to make your TextView3 scrollable?

Comment: Concerning the Weights: If you want to use weight make sure the sum of your all your LinearLayout weights is 1. If you set a weight of 0.5 on your first 2 LinearLayouts both will take 50% of available space thus the last one will not be visible